# How to make the file name display in the TableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The recorded file does not show up on the TableView
How can I show it?
I hope that the TableView Cell can show recording-yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss.m4a
Recording function is normal, but the file name can not be displayed in the TableView Cell
I hope that in the specified cell can also play I want to hear the recording

```
var recordings = [URL]()

func listRecordings() {

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    do {
        let urls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsDirectory,
                                                               includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
                                                               options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles)
        self.recordings = urls.filter({ (name: URL) -> Bool in
            return name.pathExtension == "m4a"
        })
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("something went wrong listing recordings")
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recordings.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = recordings[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
    return cell
}
```

The following is my way of archiving

```
func setupRecorder() {

    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let currentFileName = "recording-\(format.string(from: Date())).m4a"
    print(currentFileName)

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    self.soundFileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(currentFileName)
    print("writing to soundfile url: '\(soundFileURL!)'")

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: soundFileURL.absoluteString) {
        // probably won't happen. want to do something about it?
        print("soundfile \(soundFileURL.absoluteString) exists")
    }
```

Comment: does your tableView  show any other constant string ? to insure if bug is in the tableView or not

Comment: Nothing is shown in TableView

Comment: that indicates the problem with table view initialization , connect delegate , data source

Comment: @蔡家文 you will need to show us the whole tableViewController so that we can help you.. and specify whether you use storyboards or it is done programmatically

Comment: I'm sorry I was a beginner how can I show you TableView

Answer (score 0):

You have to `reload` your `tableview`.

Once you stored all `URL` values in `recordings` , then you have to call `tableview.reload()`

As you are beginner,

First, try to check, tableView's delegate and datasource methods are calling or not.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
```

If the above methods are not working, try to add below lines.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      yourTableView.dataSource = self
      yourTableView.delegate = self

}
```

If everything is working fine and if you having some URL's in your `URL array`, then `reload()` is the only issue.

Comment: When I write return 5 it appears libc ++ abi.dylib: Terminate type NSException Uncaptured exception  I have got myTableView.dataSource = self   myTableView.delegate = self

Comment: I read ur code. Two Buttons, 1.Record 2.Play. At First, record action should be trigger. if Record is nil, u r gng for recordWithPermission and u r recording else u r gng for tableVw.reloadData(). In this else case, recordings count is zero. In this method **listRecordings()**, u r adding urls to recordingsURLArray. But, u have not called this method anywhere in ur view controller.Call the above method, and try to reload ur tableview.  If u having values in recordingsURLArray, sure u will get tableview.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I am a beginner, you can demonstrate how I should modify it